# Developer Jobs search: filter for listings with an “Easy apply” button

Tags: feature-request, status-planned, stack-overflow-jobs, search

I'm too lazy to follow external application links and fill in all the info over and over again.

There should be a way to filter the search results to positions for which an application can be made directly through Developer Jobs.

P.S. This appears to be a regression from [Careers 2.0 search: filter for listings with an "apply now" button](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178705/careers-2-0-search-filter-for-listings-with-an-apply-now-button), as the answer there no longer works, and returns a 404 on the current reincarnation of the site.

Comment: Hi cnst! Jobs questions actually go on Meta Stack Overflow. :)

Comment: Was about to ask the same question, a selection box with "Easy Apply" would be great... (@Catija isn't this Meta Stack Overflow?)

Answer (score 3):

You're right: the `/jobs/applyonly` route which Matt Jibson added in response to your 2013 question is no longer in our codebase. It probably got cleaned up at some point when the candidate-facing pieces of Careers 2.0 became Stack Overflow Jobs.

<s>So, unfortunately, this is currently not possible.</s>

**UPDATE** we just restored a workaround: adding `application-type=internal` to the query string will get jobs filtered accordingly, just like with the old `/jobs/applyonly` route.

Example:

https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?application-type=internal

Making this properly accessible through the search UI is under consideration, but hopefully this will help for now.

**UPDATE 2** well, unfortunately this doesn't quite work yet in conjunction with an actual search term, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?q=c&application-type=internal. I'll dig some more shortly...

Comment: Well, time to retag it with feature-request rather then bug.

Comment: @Luuklag agreed. Updated.

Comment: Feature request completed. :)

Comment: It doesn't seem to work — https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/developer-jobs-using-c?application-type=internal — returns all non-easy-apply jobs

Comment: You're right. It doesn't work in conjunction with a search term, weird. I'll dig some more...

Comment: This does not work even without search queries currently.

Comment: @Silicabello, this doesn't work at all; this is especially annoying since all the spammy LinkedIn jobs that are now imported to Jobs; StackOverflow jobs is pretty much dead to me now — it's beyond useless.

Comment: May one day somebody create a filter bookmarklet for that. please inform me then